# Expiry of userid/key pair for Service Account

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Can anyone please guide me on the following:

I am using valence api to import data to lms system and use a windows service to do the same.

I have created a service account and use user id/key pair of this account to authenticate the valence api call.

My question is: 
Do we have an expiry for this user ID/Key pair? I have read somewhere (but not able to find out now) that it will be expired after 30 days. If that is the case, how can i prevent it from getting expired?

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime of a User ID/Key pair is a potentially configurable value. The expected lifetime of a UserID/Key pair is indefinite *until* it gets marked for expiry. A User ID/Key pair, *K*, will get marked for expiry when one of these events occur:

- The configured "lifetime" of all User ID/Key pairs, in seconds, is reached for *K* (that is, it was minted that many seconds ago). This is a single LMS configuration value that applies org-wide. By default it is set to a special value meaning "indefinite" (that is, it means "there is no natural expiry time for any User ID/Key pair), but particular LMS administrators can set, or get D2L to set, this to a concrete value (like a week, a month, whatever).
- The password of the LMS user account gets reset: either a user changes his or her own password, or an admin performs a password reset of the user account. This event will mark *all* existing User ID/Key pairs for that user for expiry.
- An LMS administrator revokes third-party application access for that user. This event will mark *all* existing User ID/Key pairs for that user for expiry.

When a User ID/Key pair gets marked for expiry it will, a short time later, get swept up and removed by a task that periodically removes all keys that are marked this way. (Typically the latency between marking a key for expiry, and removing it, is a very short period of time but it's not instant.)